# How to see all websites in IIS using appcmd list site

Tags: iis, asp.net, .net, windows

I want to see all the websites in IIS 7.5.

I typed

```
appcmd list site
```

It lists only “Default Website”. It is typed from C:Windows\System32\inetsrv. 
Any idea why it does not list other sites that are under default website?

Note: Even when I type it from C:Windows\syswow64\inetsrv. It is showing the same result.

Comment: Which IIS version are you running: 6 or 7?

Comment: I am using IIS 7.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In IIS land, "Websites" can't exist under other websites. So it sounds like from IIS' perspective, you have only one website configured.

IMO, that's a bad idea - you should use a website per, well, website, if that's what you're intending.

If you're referring to web applications or virtual directories, APPCMD LIST APP or APPCMD LIST VDIR might be more what you're interested in.

Answer (score 1):

For other people still having trouble, I had the same symptom, but this answer didn't help. APPCMD LIST still gave me incorrect info. Your solution might be the same as mine: after a while, I realized that I was mistakenly looking at my *workstation's* CMD prompt, when I thought I was looking at the server I had remoted into.

Comment: Although, I guess that could apply to just about any technical scenario and is unrelated to the particular question at hand. ;)